# Window positioning problem

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, hdmi, vlc, openbox

I have watch a movie on TV via HDMI.
Now I disonnected from TV, but VLC still loads as second screen available (but it doesn't).
I checked monitor settings, shows only default monitor (1) with default resoulution.
I attempt to change OpenBox settings (I use LXDE) in OpenBox Configuration manager -> Windows -> Placing windows:

place new windows under the mouse pointer

center new windows when they are placed

those options doesn't affect at the VLC Window.
How to load VLC in visible part of primary Monitor and Workspace?

Answer (score 0):

Move the vlc window, and close it prior to disconecting the second monitor. Vlc saves it window position when it closes.